# Splitting user_input strings, converting to uppercase & lowercase, and returning correct format

Tags: java, string

I've been trying to figure out how to create a program for a class. So far, I've gotten the rest of it down but I'm still unsure on how to do the start to it.

It requires for me to receive a name in any format: `jOhn, joHN, JoHn`
and convert it to `John`. I've been searching everywhere on how to separate them and return but I've had no luck. 
Can anybody help?

This is for Java by the way.

**EDIT:** Not sure if I ended up doing it the right way, but I ended up with this:

```
System.out.println("Please type in your first name.");
String firstName = fName.next();
String partFirstName = firstName.toUpperCase().substring(0,1);
String partFirstName2 = firstName.toLowerCase().substring(1);
String correctFirst = (partFirstName + partFirstName2);
```

Comment: Can you show us what you tried already? StackOverflow is no "do my homework" network

Answer (score 3):

Simply in Java, without any 3rd party libraries, you can iterate over each element of an array of splitted `String`s and then do:

```
Character.toUpperCase(user_input.charAt(0)) + user_input.substring(1).toLowerCase();
```

Comment: Why would you iterate over the whole String? https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#toLowerCase() is your friend. Just apply this to the `substring` you already have. No loop needed.

Comment: This won't work. For example, "JOHN" will not change at all, but should become "John"

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if this is what you are looking for but you could try the following:

**EDIT:** Thanks to Bohemian for pointing out a little bug in my code. The simplest code for the name formatting problem is `Character.toUpperCase(input.charAt(0)) + input.substring(1).toLowerCase();`. This is also what mhasen answered with so credit to him and also to Bohemian. Below contains the code snippet and all.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        String input = scan.nextLine();

        String newInput = Character.toUpperCase(charAt(0))
                          + input.substring(1).toLowerCase();

        System.out.println();
        System.out.println(newInput);

        scan.close();
    }
}
```

Comment: Please edit your answer if you want to add something instead of commenting on it.

Comment: This has a serious bug. For example "anna" will become "AnnA" :(

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Apache Commons Lang](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.commons/commons-lang3) library's `WordUtils.capitalize()`

e.g: `WordUtils.capitalize("john")` will return `"John"`.

And in order to split the string you can use split() method of String:

```
String input = "jOhn,JOhn,jOHn";
String[] values = input.split(",");
```

values will be array of String contain "jOhn","JOhn" and "jOHn"

Comment: WordUtils.capitalize would work great except that it isn't from the java standard library.